# How does the List has fast random access in Java?

Tags: java

The **RandomAccess** interface identifies that a particular ***java.util.List*** implementation has fast random access. This interface tries to define an imprecise concept: how fast is fast? The documentation provides a simple guide:

```
if repeated access using the List.get() method is faster than repeated access
using the Iterator.next() method, then the List has fast random access.
```

The two types of access are shown in the following code examples:

```
Object o;
for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
o = list.get(i);

Object o;
for (Iterator itr=list.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
o = itr.next();
```

How does the List has fast random access when its list.get() method is faster than repeated access
    using the Iterator.next() method.

Comment: Which ultra-common List implementation implements RandomAccess? What does its javadoc say?

Comment: I believe OP is referring to the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which does implement RandomAccess.

Comment: Interfaces never place any bounds on time complexity, unless specified by contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The imprecise nature of what it means to be "fast" is the reason we have the concept of algorithmic complexity, a.k.a. "big O" notation.  Random access implies that get operations have an algorithmic complexity of O(1), which is true of `ArrayList`.  By contrast, a get operation on a `LinkedList` has an algorithmic complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 2):

> How does the List has fast random access when its list.get() method is faster than repeated access using the Iterator.next() method.

It's only a suggestion that it's marked as having fast random access with the RandomAccess if the speed of list.get() is faster than the iterator.next(). The programmer programming the specific List implementation still has to choose to have their List implement RandomAccess.

It's understandable that since list.get(i) would directly query the data that such a method call would be faster than iterator.next() (for the List's that have good random access) because the next method may have some extra overhead of other method calls and other logic. If the iterator is faster, than you can probably safely bet it's because the List does not have good random access and that the iterator is faster because it's using some optimized method of going from node to node (such a List's iterator implementation probably has some access to underlying List data that would normally be private to other classes).

Answer (score 1):

The example code is indeed a bit misleading, because the comparison to an iterator-based solution detracts from the actual point:

A list should implement the [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface when the [List#get(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method has a constant asymptotic running time! (Written as O(1) in [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Consider an `ArrayList`: The data internally stored in an array. Calling `arrayList.get(1)` will take the same time as calling `arrayList.get(100000)`.

In contrast to that: A `LinkedList` does *not* offer `RandomAccess`. While you can still call `linkedList.get(1)` and `linkedList.get(100000)`, the latter will take *much* longer, because it has to traverse the whole list until it reaches the 100000th element.